# How to use continue in while loop?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I tried to use `continue` in a while loop to skip `print` number but it doesn't work.

```py
 num = int(input())

 while int(num) > 0 :
     num-=1
    print(num)
    if num == 6:
        continue
    elif num ==1:
     print("8 Numbers Printed Successfully.")
     break
#i want to remove number six
```

Comment: Your print(num) is before the continue part. That won't skip the printing of the number, it will print the number and then skip over the loop. Just move the print(num) line to the bottom and that should work :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
num = int(input())

while num > 0 :
    num -= 1
    if num == 6: 
        continue

    elif num == 1:
        print("8 Numbers Printed Successfully.")
        break
    
    print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your print line should be after the if-else block

```
num = int(input())

while int(num) > 0:
    num -= 1
    # print(num) => if you print here, it does not check the condition
    if num == 6:
        continue
    elif num == 1:
        print("8 Numbers Printed Successfully.")
        break
    # print number here
    print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, how do you know it's been 8 numbers? The input can be any number. Secondly, if you want to print every number but `6` you need to move the `num -= 1` too. Being there, it won't print the first number.

Try this if you don't insist on using `continue`:

```
num = int(input())

printed_numbers = 0
while int(num) > 0 :
    if num != 6:
        print(num)
        printed_numbers += 1
    num -= 1
print("{} Numbers Printed Successfully.".format(printed_numbers))
```

Or this, if you want to test `continue`:

```
num = int(input())

printed_numbers = 0
while int(num) > 0 :
    if num == 6:
        num -= 1
        continue
    print(num)
    printed_numbers += 1
    num -= 1
print("{} Numbers Printed Successfully.".format(printed_numbers))
```

Finally, If you're ok with the `num -= 1` there:

```
num = int(input())

printed_numbers = 0
while int(num) > 0 :
    num -= 1
    if num == 6:
        continue
    print(num)
    printed_numbers += 1
print("{} Numbers Printed Successfully.".format(printed_numbers))
```

**NOTE**: I'm using `printed_numbers` because `if` the input is less than `6` you will print all the numbers `else` you'll have one less. You can use this condition instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are print the number before the condition. chnage the code as follows.

```
num = int(input())

while int(num) > 0 :
    num-=1
    if num != 6:
        print(num)
    elif num == 1:
      print("8 Numbers Printed Successfully.")
      break
#i want to remove number six
```